# Powershell commands for modifying files if accessed times is within a time window

Tags: windows-8, powershell

I'm trying to learn Windows powershell and in particular, would like to write a script to operate on all files within a folder (including subdirectories). The script will examine each file and if the file creation time is within a window, say 2pm-6pm, then the creation time should be set to a given datetime, $my_date.

I have the following but am struggling to get it to work. I wonder if anyone could please help?

```
Get-Childitem |
ForEach-Object {
$date = $_.CreationTime
if ( ($date.ToString('HH') -eq 14) -or ($date.ToString('HH') -eq 15) -or ($date.ToString('HH') -eq 16) -or ($date.ToString('HH') -eq 17) -or ($date.ToString('HH') -eq 18))
{$_.CreationTime=$my_date}
```

Comment: A few comments (I will probably post back with an answer later): The if piece should really be a where-object clause (something like `where-object{$_.CreationTime -gt ...`).

As far as actually setting the creationTime, take a look at [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx)

Comment: You are missing a curly bracket at the end for the `ForEach-Object {`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `..` notation in Powershell to create range of integer values and you can use the `-in` operator to check if a value appears in the range.

```
# Define a range from 2pm - 6pm 
$hourRange = 14..24

# New date to set.
$myDate = [datetime]::Now

# Get files & folders
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { 

    # Which creation times fall within the hour range.
    $_.CreationTime.Hour -in $hourRange } | ForEach-Object {

        # Change the creation time.
        $_.CreationTime = $myDate
}
```